# Angular ng-repeat index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using Angular ng-repeat like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{ active:isSet($index) }" ng-click="setTab($index, tab)">&nbsp;{{tab}}&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

But the resulting HTML is like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{ active:isSet($index) }" ng-click="setTab($index, tab)" class="ng-scope ng-binding">&nbsp;First item&nbsp;</li>
  <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{ active:isSet($index) }" ng-click="setTab($index, tab)" class="ng-scope ng-binding">&nbsp;Second item&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Wheras I would like the $index to be rendered correctly, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{ active:isSet(0) }" ng-click="setTab(0, tab)" class="ng-scope ng-binding">&nbsp;First item&nbsp;</li>
  <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{ active:isSet(1) }" ng-click="setTab(1, tab)" class="ng-scope ng-binding">&nbsp;Second item&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try <li ng-repeat="(key, tab) in tabs" ng-class="{ active:isSet(key) }" ng-click="setTab(key, tab)">&nbsp;{{tab}}&nbsp;</li>

Comment: You forgot to use 'track by' ng-repeat="item in array track by $index"

Comment: You won't see the values of `$index` in the view ...why do you think you need the last display? WHat problems is it causing ?

Comment: @Vinny using `track by` won't change the behavior  of using `$index` in this case and won't print it to the view either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/409L1qt9/1/).

Although the `$index` value is not evaluated and shown in the element, actually the value is passed into the function correctly:

```
angular.module("Joy", [])
.controller("JoyCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isSet = function (index) {
        console.log(index);
        return index % 2 === 0;
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="Joy" ng-controller="JoyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]" ng-class="{'active': isSet($index)}">{{i}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quite right! Despite the $index not renering in HTML, all seemed to be working anyway - the function is being called with the correct arguments - strange subtle behaviour from Angular!

Comment: @NickJ not strange at all ..`$index` is a variable

Comment: As a Java developer, anything Javascript makes my poor little brain ooze right out of my ears in terminal confusion :)